# SQLite: SELECT IN by a 100K element list

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have an SQLite table of ~1M rows. Each row has a structure of (`docId`, `docBLOB`). Each `docBlob` is nearly 20Kb.

I have to perform `SELECT` by an externally provided list of `docID`s. Each list may be nearly 100K elements long. How can I do it more efficiently?

Maybe there is a way to make `SELECT * IN docBlobTable WHERE docId IN ( [MEGALIST] )` statement?

Comment: Have you tried indexing the table maybe?

Comment: Yes, I created an index on docId.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the IDs into a temporary table, then use:

```sql
SELECT * FROM docBlobTable WHERE docId IN (SELECT ID FROM TempTable)
```

or:

```sql
SELECT docBlobTable.*
FROM docBlobTable
JOIN TempTable ON docBlobTable.docId = TempTable.ID
```